# Odoo : make computed field inherits permissions from dependencies

Tags: odoo

In this case, I would like that permissions on `something` be inherited from `account.move` because it is dependent on it. How do I do that ?

```py
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    something = fields.Float('Something', compute="_compute_something")

    def _compute_something(self):
        self.env['account.move'].search(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sudo() in the search method.
sudo() use for super admin permission. you can access all recodes of all modules.

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
_inherit = "res.partner"

something = fields.Float('Something', compute="_compute_something")

def _compute_something(self):
    self.env['account.move'].sudo().search(...)
```